# Does myAssembly.xmlSerializer.dll always get generated?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, iis

I have a web service that does not use any xml attributes for serialization. I just return a string from the web service. In this case, does a serialization dll get created?

The reason I ask is I keep seeing c:\windows\temp\xxxxx.dll (where xxxxx is a random sequence of characters) every couple of weeks the web service is running. One solution is to pre-compile using sgen.exe and that might solve the problem.

Also, I saw a link that said only do this for client side libraries, but this error is on the web service side (server side), so can I still use sgen.exe?

JD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call the `XmlSerializer` constructor it will check the type you are trying to serialize and it will generate a temporary assembly. If the assembly already exists it will reuse it. So if your web service is a classic ASMX service it will use `XmlSerializer` on every request, no matter the return type. These temporary assemblies are part of the serialization process and in my opinion you shouldn't worry too much about them.

Comment: Thanks Darin. So sgen.exe will not help avoid the error? I was thinking about changing the application pool recycle period from the default 29 hours to about 15 hours and see if that has any effect.

Comment: @JD, you say that you see all these temporary assemblies generated in the temp folder but you didn't mention anything about errors?

Comment: @Darin: After a couple of weeks, each web service generates an error "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\windows\Temp\xxxxxx.dll'" where xxxxx changes on each request. I posted this a while back : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682425/web-service-error-that-has-occurred-several-times

Comment: @Darin: You said that the xmlSerializer is called on every request. I thought it was only done on the first request and then it was cached?

Comment: `XmlSerializer` is instantiated on every request, but it will reuse the temporary assembly generated on previous requests.

Comment: @Darin: Okay, thanks. Any ideas on my previous reply regarding a previous post.