# Error - Could not find file 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\xxxxxx.dll'

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, sitecore, sitecore6

Getting this intermittent error on the websites on our dev server. Whenever the user is in the Content Editor, randomly gets this message on the page or even while accessing any web page from the website. 
Using Sitecore 6.3.
.NET Framework being used is 3.5

When the event logs are checked it gives this warning

The error is

```
Event Type: Warning 
Event Source:   ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0 
Event Category: Web Event  
Event ID:   1309 
Date:       3/26/2013 
Time:       9:26:02 AM 
User:       N/A 
Computer:   XXXXXX 
Description: 
Event code: 3005  
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.  
Event time: 3/26/2013 9:26:02 AM  
Event time (UTC): 3/26/2013 9:26:02 AM  
Event ID: 5d6aa660141a4ca0966f5a3fad3b0df6  
Event sequence: 726  
Event occurrence: 2  
Event detail code: 0    
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1829939302/Root-1-130087629613322311 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: D:\WebSites\Dev\dev1.cms.local\ 
    Machine name: XXXXX    
Process information: 
    Process ID: 7728 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE    
Exception information: 
    Exception type: FileNotFoundException 
    Exception message: Could not find file 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\vhn7lf5h.dll'.    
Request information: 
    Request URL: http://dev1.cms.local/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=RichTextEditor&da=core&id=12b8259DD4D-BD3D-4035-80A4-BC8CB03D260D12d&ed=FIELD280399344&vs&la=en&fld=12b878702CE-F97D-40CB-8F1D-AA7AEBEC8B2412d&so=

Request path: /sitecore/shell/default.aspx 
User host address: 111.11.111.111 
User: sitecore\Anonymous 
Is authenticated: False 
Authentication Type:  
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE    
Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 45 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)    at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)    at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)    at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)    at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)    at Sitecore.CodeDom.Compiler.CSharpCompiler.Compile(String sourceFile, String code, String assemblyFile, StringCollection referencedAssemblies)    at Sitecore.CodeDom.Compiler.CSharpCompiler.Compile(String code, StringCollection referencedAssemblies)    at Sitecore.CodeDom.Compiler.CSharpCompiler.SourceToMemory(String code, StringCollection referencedAssemblies)    at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FolderControlSource.BuildControlAssembly(XmlNode fileNode, String& assemblyKey, String& assemblyFile)    at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FolderControlSource.GetControlAssembly(String controlName, String& assemblyKey)    at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FolderControlSource.ResolveType(String controlName, Boolean includeDynamicTypes)    at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlSource.GetControlType(String namespacePrefix, String controlName, String mode, Boolean includeDynamicTypes)    at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControlType(String controlName, String mode, Boolean includeDynamicTypes)    at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControl(Control parent, String controlName, String mode, Object[] properties, AllowGenericControl allowGeneric)    at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControl(String controlName)    at Sitecore.Shell.DefaultPage.OnInit(EventArgs e)    at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [blog post](http://devatheart.azurewebsites.net/2011/04/18/troubleshooting-xmlserializer-failure/) definitely solved the problem that we were facing.

We had this piece of code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(RetrievedURL);
```

which was generating IE processes (Since IE was the default browser on the webserver) in the background on the button click and opening webpage.

Not a smart thing to have but we removed that code and it has definitely stopped the IE processes in the background.

Thanks for the research and this blog post Slobodan Stipic, a.k.a. Slobo.

Hope this solution helps others in future.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar exception message *Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\2vddx2j2.0.cs' could not be found'* and the Content Editor would not load.

```
Exception: Sitecore.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerException
Message: Source file 'C:\windows\TEMP\2vddx2j2.0.cs' could not be found
Source: File: , line 0
   at Sitecore.CodeDom.Compiler.CSharpCompiler.AssertResults(String sourceFile, CompilerResults results)
   at Sitecore.CodeDom.Compiler.CSharpCompiler.Compile(String sourceFile, String code, String assemblyFile, StringCollection referencedAssemblies)
   at Sitecore.CodeDom.Compiler.CSharpCompiler.Compile(String code, StringCollection referencedAssemblies)
   at Sitecore.CodeDom.Compiler.CSharpCompiler.SourceToMemory(String code, StringCollection referencedAssemblies)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FolderControlSource.BuildControlAssembly(XmlNode fileNode, String& assemblyKey, String& assemblyFile)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FolderControlSource.GetControlAssembly(String controlName, String& assemblyKey)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FolderControlSource.ResolveType(String controlName, Boolean includeDynamicTypes)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlSource.GetControlType(String namespacePrefix, String controlName, String mode, Boolean includeDynamicTypes)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControlType(String controlName, String mode, Boolean includeDynamicTypes)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControl(Control parent, String controlName, String mode, Object[] properties, AllowGenericControl allowGeneric)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControl(String controlName, String mode, Object[] properties, AllowGenericControl allowGeneric)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControl(String controlName, String mode, Object[] properties)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControl(String controlName, String mode)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControl(String controlName)
   at Sitecore.Shell.DefaultPage.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Turns out the AppPool user, **ApplicationPoolIdentity**, did not have write access to the C:\Windows\Temp\ directory.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem on Windows 7 - I had to add Network Service user in security tab for Windows\Temp. I see it's another problem than the question in the top, but I'm glad I found this answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a Virtual Machine, try to restart it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set IIS Application Pool identity to Network Service. 
Make sure C:\Windows\Temp has Network Service user in security tab with full controll